# Different derivations of dieletric polarization charges in Griffiths and Feynman

Tags: electrostatics, charge, polarization, dielectric, dipole

I am reading Griffiths's Introduction to Electrodynamics (3rd edition). In the part of dieletric polarization (p.166), the author first adopts the potential for a single dipole:

$$V(\mathbf r)=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\mathbf{\hat r}\cdot\mathbf p}{r^2},\tag{4.8}$$

and then uses some vector analysis transformation to get the forms of surface bound charge and volume bound charge. But later I find that Feynman in his [lecture](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_10.html) shows that one can get the formulas for surface and volume bound charges using only simple physical pictures:

$$\sigma_{pol}=\mathbf P\cdot\mathbf n\tag{10.12}$$ $$\rho_{pol}=-\nabla\cdot\mathbf P.\tag{10.16}$$

Feynman's derivation is simple and clear and he didn't refer to the form of the dipole potential. Therefore, it is clear that the form of the potential for a dipole in Griffiths's derivation is unnecessary. But how THAT form of dipole potential comes into play in the derivation of $(10.12)$ and $(10.16)$ is unclear. Can someone explain it?

Comment: I don't have a copy of the 3rd edition on me, but the 4th edition has a section titled "Physical Interpretation of Bound Charges" that derives the formulae for the bound charges directly via a geometric argument similar to the one provided by Feynman. If my memory serves me correctly, the 2nd edition (which I used back in school) also had this section, so I would expect that the 3rd edition also has it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link comes from the charge density distribution to generate the dipole field. To make the link explicit, I’ll use distributions. You don’t need the potential of a dipole to deduce the charge density.

Recall that and electric monopole of charge $q$ at position $r_0$ has charge distribution:
$$
\rho(r)=q\delta(r-r_0)
$$
An ideal electric dipole of moment $p$ at position $r_0$ can be seen as the limit of two opposing infinite charges at the same location that are scaled to keep a finite dipole moment. Its charge density is therefore:
$$
\rho(r)=p\cdot\nabla_{r_0}\delta(r-r_0)
$$
This is the true definition of a dipole from which you derive Griffiths’ and Feynman’s approach.

Solving the Poisson equation (setting $\epsilon_0=1$):
$$
\Delta V+\rho=0
$$
gives you Griffiths’ formula of the dipole field. The simplest way to see this is to apply $p\cdot\nabla_{r_0}$ on the monopole field (Coulomb potential) since it commutes with the Laplacian.

When you have $N$ dipoles indexed by $i$, the charge density is obtained by adding each contribution:
$$
\rho(r)=\sum_i p_i\cdot\nabla_{r_i}\delta(r-r_i)
$$
In the continuous limit, this becomes:
$$
\begin{align}
\rho(r) &=\int P(r’)\cdot\nabla_{r’}\delta(r-r’)d^3r’\\
&= -\int\nabla_{r’}\cdot P(r’)\delta(r-r’)d^3r’\\
&= -\nabla\cdot P(r)
\end{align}
$$

You can actually deduce (10.6) from (10.12). Indeed, a discontinuity is $P$ will give a Dirac delta supported on the surface of discontinuity which amounts to surface charges given by (10.6).

Hope this helps.